# Select DISTINCT on a single column using Silverstripe ORM

Tags: silverstripe

My table:

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID | RoomTypeId | ChargeTypeId | Name |
-----------------------------------------
|  1 |    23      |    32        |  DD  |
|  2 |    26      |    32        |  DD  |
|  3 |    28      |    31        |  CC  |
-----------------------------------------
```

The ORM does already DISTINCT by default, but does so on every column and returns all 3

The return I need:

```
-----------------------
| ChargeTypeId | Name |
-----------------------
|      32      |  DD  |
|      31      |  CC  |
-----------------------
```

Hoping there is actually a implemented method of achieving this without having to `DB::query()`

Comment: I haven't used these methods before but I would have a look at http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_setQueriedColumns and http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_distinct

Comment: Thanks @GavinBruce I will look into these, for now I found my solution in `toMap()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `toMap()` will create a DISTINCT query based on your chosen columns

**Example**:

```
$result = \ChargeTypes::get()->toMap("ChargeTypeId", "Name")
```

**$result->toArray()**:

```
array(2) {
    [32]=>
  string(2) "DD"
    [6]=>
  string(2) "CC"
}
```

**UPDATE** I don't believe that this actually creates a DISTINCT query it just worked in my case and the following will clearly elaborate as to why

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[32] = "DD";
$myArray[32] = "DD";
$myArray[32] = "DD";
$myArray[6] = "CC";
$myArray[6] = "CC";
var_dump($myArray);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
    [32]=>
  string(2) "DD"
    [6]=>
  string(2) "CC"
}
```

So in theory as long as your first key is unique, this isn't actually that bad of solution despite the redundant iterations.