# Silverstripe - Distinct Dropdown Fields

Tags: php, distinct, silverstripe, dropdown

I am trying to populate a dropdown with states/provinces from a dataobject but there are many records with the same state. How can I only show distinct states?

This returns the distinct states:

```
$states= DataObject::get()->distinct(true)->column('State');
```

This shows as distinct values in my dropdown:

```
DropdownField::create('State', 'State', $states)
                    ->setEmptyString('(Select one)'),
```

But this only shows the values in the dropdown as the states and not the ID's as the state. How can I populate the ID's as well?

It doesn't like it when I add them to an array.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338922/select-distinct-on-a-single-column-using-silverstripe-orm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an `SS_Map` and `array_unique()`. It’s not as efficient as manually constructing a database query, but it’ll get the job done just fine and won’t be an issue unless you have many thousands of rows.

```
$statesMap = MyStateDataObject::get()->map('ID', 'State');
$states = array_unique($statesMap->toArray());
$field = DropdownField::create('State', 'State', $states);
```

The other way is to build a database query to do this, something like:

```
$query = SQLSelect::create()
    ->setSelect(array('ID', 'State'))
    ->setFrom('MyStateDataObject')
    ->setGroupBy('State');

$states = array();
foreach ($query->execute() as $row) {
    $states[$row['ID']] = $row['State'];
}
```